# Scrollbar disappears from Tkinter canvas, and refuses to adhere to side-packing

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

1. I am trying to attach a scrollbar to a Tkinter canvas.
2. To test the scrollbar, I dynamically generated 100 "Hello World" labels, and packed these inside a content-holding frame.

My code fails. Issues:

1. The scrollbar does not even appear.
2. The content frame instead expands to the full height of the 100-packed labels.
3. Interestingly, the scrollbar magically reappears if I shift `self.frame_for_content.pack()` *under* `self.scrollbar.pack()`. (Why this is so is beyond me, but the scrollbar still does not work or adhere to the `side` packing behaviour either.)

I have attempted to incorporate some of Brian Oakley's suggestions on `scroll region` and `bbox`, to no avail.

I have reduced the code to the bare minimum, but am unable to push through. Would appreciate the help.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class TestGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.frame_for_content = tk.Frame(self.canvas)

        self.canvas_frame = self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame_for_content, anchor=tk.NW)

        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.frame_for_content.pack()
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        for i in range(100):
            tk.Label(self.frame_for_content, text="Hello World - " + str(i)).pack()

        self.update()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))

TestGUI().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't want `self.frame_for_content.pack()` because you're using the canvas like a geometry manager for that widget, so `self.canvas.create_window` takes the place of `.pack` or `.grid`.

To get the sizes right, you can get the width & height from the canvas bounding box.

I think this does what you want:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TestGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.frame_for_content = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas_frame = self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.frame_for_content, anchor=tk.NW)
        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        for i in range(100):
            tk.Label(self.frame_for_content, text="Hello World - " + str(i)).pack()

        self.update()
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL)
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set, 
            width=bbox[2], height=bbox[3], scrollregion=bbox)

TestGUI().mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! This one works as intended, but may I ask: why should `Scrollbar` be attached to `self` instead of `self.canvas`, and why is `self.update()` necessary?

Comment: @anonnoir No worries. **1** To put the Scrollbar directly on the Canvas you'd have to use `self.canvas.create_window` and fiddle with the geometry to get its location right; it'd be simpler to put it into the `frame_for_content`. But in either case you get the undesirable behaviour of the Scrollbar scrolling with the Canvas it's sitting on. **2** We need to call `self.update()` (or even better, `self.update_idletasks()`) to give Tkinter a chance to complete the geometry management of the GUI elements we've specified so far. If we don't do that, the `bbox` will be `(0, 0, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I appreciate it.